# VBA Searching an Excel Spreadsheet and Highlighting Results based on user Current Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data in sheet one of a workbook and I am looking to find every other instance of each value in the column within different sheets of the workbook. I would like to then Highlight the results. I found something online that lets the user prompt the thing they are looking for then highlights which looks like this:

```
Sub HighlightSpecificValue()

'PURPOSE: Highlight all cells containing a specified values
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

'What value do you want to find?
  fnd = InputBox("I want to hightlight cells containing...", "Highlight")

'End Macro if Cancel Button is Clicked or no Text is Entered
  If fnd = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

    'Test to see if anything was found
      If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
      Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
  
    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
  
  Loop

'Highlight Found cells yellow
  rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

'Report Out Message
  MsgBox rng.Cells.Count & " cell(s) were found containing: " & fnd

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
  MsgBox "No cells containing: " & fnd & " were found in this worksheet"

End Sub
```

Instead of an input box is it possible to have the input be a selection?

Comment: `fnd = selection.value`

Comment: replace  { fnd = InputBox("I want to hightlight cells containing...", "Highlight") } by  fnd = selection.text/target.text and place this code in worksheet selection change event. add condition to check target.column

Comment: Do you need `all the values in the column` or just a selection? Will you be searching for  cells containing the string or being equal to the string? Will the other worksheets be defined by a list of worksheets or just all other worksheets in the workbook? If `all the values in the column`, will this be running by pressing a button on the first worksheet or by changing a value in the specified column and will the specified column contain values or formulas? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65497719/edit) your post with any additional information (details) you can think of.